# Why is the placeholder text in my search bar not appearing in Firefox

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, cross-browser, placeholder

I have a cross browser issue in which the placeholder text that is nested in my search bar of my Rails app does not appear in Mozilla despite working terrific in all other browsers.

I have looked around for an answer without success.

### Search bar rendered in Safari, Chrome and Opera.

[image: Search bar rendered in Safari, Chrome and Opera]

### Search bar rendered using Firefox.

[image: Search bar rendered using Firefox]

### _header.html.erb

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <%= image_tag('nippon.svg', alt: "Nippon Beauty", class: "navbar-brand-icon") %>
    </a> 
  </div>

      <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What type of Skincare product would you like?">

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li> 
      <li><%= link_to "Signup", new_user_registration_path %></li>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Account Settings", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
      <% else %>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

### CSS

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

 body{
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }


 .searchTerm {
   position: absolute;
   left: 550px;
   top: 20px;
   width: 370px;
   border: 15px;
   background: #F2F2F2;
   padding: 25px;
   height: 40px;
   border-radius: 8px;
 }
```

Comment: There's a `</div><!-- /container -->` missing in your code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text input placeholders not displaying in IE and Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507731/text-input-placeholders-not-displaying-in-ie-and-firefox)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the total amount of padding you're using is greater than the height of your input.

`padding: 25px;`

Is the same as

`padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 25px;`

So the amount of vertical padding is 50px, but you set the height to only 40px. Make your height greater than the amount of padding and you'll see the text.

---

Of course, the question becomes why *doesn't* this result in a problem in other browsers. It looks like Chrome deals with it by clipping off the padding when the padding is larger than the given height. If I take the height out of your CSS in Chrome, the search box actually gets bigger. I'm guessing the other browsers do the same thing.

My guess is that the problem is the order in which the CSS is applied in different browsers. Chrome adds the padding, then changes the height of the result. Firefox changes the height, then adds the padding to the result. Again, just a guess, but that's what appears to be happening.

Comment: BSMP.  you are a legend sir. This worked terrific. thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify this only happens when `box-sizing: border-box;` and a fixed height is set on the input field. Such as in the Bootstrap framework. An alternative solution is to set the top and bottom padding to 0 and just set the height as required. As discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507731/text-input-placeholders-not-displaying-in-ie-and-firefox/28087860#28087860